# How to get back old configurations of app windows if lost because of reboot?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, reboot

Macbook froze (the rainbow beachball was just twirling) because of low memory, so I needed to do a reboot using the power button.

Might have done a safe mode reboot (not sure).

After I restarted all of the windows, PDFs, etc where not back on the screen. Restarted again choosing not to start up with the same windows, hoping the old setup would appear again.

This time some app windows such as Evernote and Safari was back to normal but not the PDFs.

Is there some way to get back the old setup of app windows? Perhaps with Time Machine or some backup cache.

Comment: Under the circumstances, the only way to get the documents/windows back to where you had them is to manually reopen them.

Comment: It's for a research job I have been working on. I wouldn't be able to find them all again. ☹️

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to get everything back through Time Machine?

Comment: Assuming the _default settings_ in play and PDF's were opened in **Preview**, then no, **Time Machine** isn't going to make a difference for any document opened in **Preview** as it only saves the information when the **System Preferences** > **General** > **[] Close windows when quitting an app** checkbox is unchecked and **Preview** was closed properly, which it wouldn't have if the **OS** froze and you preformed a _forced shutdown_ as you stated.

Comment: When opening the preview app (the one that opens all the PDFs, then all PDFs that were open opened again!)

Comment: So there might be some app windows where I had info on that is forgotten somewhere but it seems most of my headache should be gone. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

By opening up the OSX preview app there is a chance that the PDFs will show up again. That worked for me.